# Using lru-cache from NPM with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to use `lru-cache` in my TypeScript Node.js app.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache

`package.json` dependencies:

```
"lru-cache": "^4.1.1",  
"@types/lru-cache": "^4.1.0",
```

My TS code:

```
import { LRU } from 'lru-cache';
...
  const cacheOptions: any = {};
  cacheOptions.max = 100;
  cacheOptions.maxAge = 60 * 1000;
  const cache: any = LRU(cacheOptions);
  cache.put(key, value);
```

The `cache` variable is always coming back to me as an empty object, so the `cache.put()` always fails.

I have tried every possible permutation of the import statement for this, but nothing works:

```
import { LRU } from 'lru-cache';
import * as LRU from 'lru-cache';
import LRU = require('lru-cache');
const LRU: any = require('lru-cache');
```

Does anyone see what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: `import 'lru-cache'`?

Comment: It is a default import: import LRU from 'lru-cache'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lru-cache uses `get` and `set` (not `put`).

Usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache#usage

Comment: No worries! Honestly this got me the first time I used `lru-cache` as well! :)